# Query Importrange Error - Query completed with an empty output

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please, can anyone fix this formula? Getting the following error: Query completed with an empty output.

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("17qPHp2PXaS9JdwJdNjksdjksdyIyWgR6kdN9-zWMA", "clientdata!A:E"), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = 'Active' AND (Col2 = 'Facebook' OR Col2 = 'Twitter')")

Comment: that means that there aren't rows that match those conditions. What do you see if you remove the QUERY?

Comment: As @ztiaa mentions, if we could see the values returned from the IMPORTRANGE function we could have more visibility to determine what could be wrong with the QUERY and try to get you a solution.